# Not able to add fields to my content type in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, cck, custom-fields

In my localhost drupal site I have created a content type "Scholarship". Now I need to add few more fields (checkboxes, radio etc) to it.

The problem is, I cannot see "Add new fields" option anywhere on the page. When I click the "Manage Fields" options I am redirected to the "content/node-type/scholarship/fields" and there is no option for adding new fields.

Any idea on what is causing this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct permissions in /admin/user/permissions.  I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: I have enabled all the permissions for admin (myself). But when I go to manage fields all I see is three columns. The first one containing my current fields for that content type, the second column has text saying "Add a field" and the third column also has text "Add a field". All these columns are separated by vertical lines. I cannot see any add fields "button" there.

Answer (score 0):

check $closure in the end of page.tpl.php and try clear cache once.

Comment: there is $closure at the end (just before the body tag is closed). The surprising thing is this problem had not occurred before, but after installing some new module this stuff started happening. I disabled the modules that I thought were the culprits but the problem persists. Any idea on which module can possibly cause this type of anomaly.

Comment: It seems that the reason for the "manage fields" option not showing up was because of Form Builder Module.
I disabled form builder, form builder example, form builder node ui, form builder webform ui. After disabling these modules, I can now finally add cck fields to my content type.

Answer (score 0):

use cck module download and enable it then it show managefiled option for content type..